# I'm trying to configure a Soap Client to use Certificate from Smart card for authentication in Spring boot (java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, certificate, client

I'm trying to configure a Soap Client to use Certificate from Smart card for authentication in Spring boot (java)
I can access the certificate by code:

```
private Certificate getCert() throws Exception { 
     KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
     ks.load(null, null); 
     String alias = "Hubba";
     return  ks.getCertificate(alias);
    }
```

but I'm not sure how to put this in the Soap client:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.hubba.bu");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public SoapClient soapClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
    client.setWebServiceTemplate(webServiceTemplate());
    return client;
}

@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
  WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
  webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
  webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
  webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("https://test.com/api");
}
```

Can someone advise me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/altfatterz/spring-ws-with-keystore/blob/master/consumer/src/main/java/com/zoltanaltfatter/HttpsWebServiceClientConfig.java) of a Spring Boot WS project with producer and consumer apps. Basically, you have to use `WebServiceTemplateBuilder.additionalMessageSenders()` during build process of `WebServiceTemplate` bean.